# PHP - add 1 day to date format mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: php, date

```
<?php
    $date = "04-15-2013";
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date);
    echo date('m-d-Y', $date);
?>
```

This is driving me crazy and seems so simple. I'm pretty new to PHP, but I can't figure this out. The echo returns `01-01-1970`.

The $date will be coming from a `POST` in the format `m-d-Y`, I need to add one day and have it as a new variable to be used later.

Do I have to convert $date to `Y-m-d`, add 1 day, then convert back to `m-d-Y`?
Would I be better off learning how to use `DateTime`?

Comment: If your date will be coming in from a `POST`, then you're probably better off using `$tomorrow = date('m-d-Y',strtotime("+1 days"));` (Fabio's answer) and `$tomorrow = $_POST[$tomorrow];` in your data collecting script.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

there you go

```
$date = "04-15-2013";
$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
$tomorrow = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($date1 . "+1 days"));

echo $tomorrow;
```

this will output

```
04-16-2013
```

**Documentation for both function**

[date](http://php.net/manual/it/function.date.php)

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know it would not recognize '-'. I have no problem changing it all over to '/'. Thank you!

Answer (score 63):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '04-15-2013');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('m-d-Y');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bYVNGB)

Or in PHP 5.4+

```
echo (DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '04-15-2013'))->modify('+1 day')->format('m-d-Y');
```

**reference**

- [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 17):

```
$date = strtotime("+1 day");
echo date('m-d-y',$date);
```

Answer (score 3):

use http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php like

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

output

```
2000-01-2
```

Answer (score 1):

The format you've used is not recognized by strtotime(). Replace

```
$date = "04-15-2013";
```

by

```
$date = "04/15/2013";
```

Or if you want to use `-` then use the following line with the year in front:

```
$date = "2013-04-15";
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I wanted same alike thing,
To get one year backward date, for a given date! :-)

With the hint of above answer from @mohammad mohsenipur
I got to the following [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php), via his given link!

Luckily, there is a method same as date_add method, named date_sub method! :-)
I do the following to get done what I wanted!

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 years'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

Hopes this answer will help somebody too! :-)

Good luck guys!