# PHP and MySQL - Comparing dates near maturity

Tags: php, mysql, variables, date, maturity

I'm trying to do a system that compare an specific date (`$date`) with the atual date (`date('Y/m/d')`), but I need to color this `$date` when he is one week to the atual date (near the maturity date). I don't know if you can understand me, my english is bad...

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Can you post some code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Do it in the MySQL query:

```
SELECT maturity_date,
       maturity_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AS near_maturity,
       ...
```

Then your PHP code can use `if ($row['near_maturity')` to color the date.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't find out how to use it. I tryed:
`<?php
   $sql = mysql_query("
      SELECT id,
      name,
      value,
      date,
      date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AS near_maturity
      FROM test
      ORDER BY id DESC
   ",$link);
   $result = mysql_num_rows($sql);
?>

<?php
   if ($row['near_maturity'){
      //code here
   }
?>`

I just don't know how to use it... If I do an echo in `near_maturity`,  he displays '1'...

Comment: `//code here` should be whatever you want to do to color the output, like `echo '<span style="color: red;">';`

Comment: Yes, I put the color code, but he paints the '1'... I want he paints the right date, the date in the database. I tryed like this:
`<?php if ($result['near_maturity']){ ?> <span style="color:#f00;"> <?php echo $result['near_maturity']; ?> </span> <?php }; ?>`. He displays '1' red.

Comment: You should echo `$result['date']`, not `$result['near_maturity']`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '04-15-2013');
$maturityDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '04-20-2013');
$maturityDateMinus10Days = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '04-10-2013');

if ($date > $maturityDateMinus10Days
    && $date < $maturityDate) {
    echo 'date is within 10 days of maturity 10';
}
```

You can test it by copying and pasting here http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Ref. [PHP - add 1 day to date format mm-dd-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018629/php-add-1-day-to-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy)

Ref. [How can I check if the current date/time is past a set date/time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832467/php-how-can-i-check-if-the-current-date-time-is-past-a-set-date-time)

Comment: My $date needs to be a variable from database. Does it work in the same way? How?

Comment: Looks like you have your answer from @Barmar, but you could just do like `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $dateFromDb);`